# How can I write a cmdlet similar to Out-String?

Tags: powershell

I would like to write a PowerShell cmdlet script that works like `Out-String`, but with an unlimited line width and without any padding at the end of lines to a specific width.

It should have output like the following code, except preferably there would be no maximum line width and any trailing whitespace that is actually in the input for a line is preserved.

```
$x = ls;
[regex]::Replace(($x| Out-String -Width 1024), "\ +([\r\n])", '$1');
```

(If you print `$x | Out-String -Width 1024` directly, you can see the extra spaces at the end of the lines.)

Comment: Why is this needed, when you can simply output a string?

Comment: There are extra spaces because the width is 1024. Get rid of the width parameter and the extra spaces go away. With PowerShell you don't need to dynamically assign arrays. Also there is no such thing a unlimited string. "Why is this needed, when you can simply output a string?"

Comment: The default width is 80, so leaving it off just makes things worse.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create a "no frills" implementation of [`Out-String`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113368) with something like:

```powershell
filter ConvertTo-String { "$_" }
```

This coerces any object passed to the filter into a string (using PowerShell string expansion to call [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) on non-null objects, and changing `$null` into an empty string).

Running the filter on an example input of five elements below, the filter will convert them into the corresponding string values (the integer becomes `'1'`, the double `'2.3'`, null `''`, the string `'four'`, and the hashtable `'System.Collections.Hashtable'`):

```powershell
1,2.3,$null,'four',@{five=6} | ConvertTo-String
```

Running the filter on the output of [`Get-ChildItem`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) (alias `ls`) produces similar results:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem

    Directory: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----       13 Jul 2009  11:56 PM            en-US
d----       13 Jul 2009  11:52 PM            Examples
d----       13 Jul 2009  11:52 PM            Modules
-a---       13 Jul 2009   8:14 PM     452608 powershell.exe
-a---       12 May 2012  10:28 AM        436 powershell.exe.config
...

PS> Get-ChildItem | ConvertTo-String
en-US
Examples
Modules
powershell.exe
powershell.exe.config
...
```

When you convert objects into strings, you lose the information and functionality the objects originally contained:

- Converting a hashtable into a string just gives you its type name. You cannot access the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.count.aspx) of the hashtable, or learn anything about its elements.
- Converting a file system object into a string gives you the relative path to the item from where it was requested. You cannot access the [full path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx) of the item, get the [`LastWriteTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime.aspx), determine the [`Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) of a file item, or even test whether the item *is* a file or a directory (without making additional calls).

In fact, the only safe conversion that can be made is if the original object **is** a string. This is also the only time when there would be "trailing whitespace".

(In other words, it is generally better practice to stick with objects for as long as possible, rather than trying to emulate the limitations of string-based shells ;-)